# Jest failed to compute the absolute file path from relative path

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am Testing the javascript file with jest which having relative file path like

```
fs.readFileSync('../configuration_service/configuration_files/test.js')
```

If I test the above javascript file with jest, by importing into the test.js file, I am getting `ENOENT: no such file or directory`. Is there any way to test those file, other than mocking the file path request or providing the absolute file path (Because the javascript code should run on any machine.Removing the relative path is not advisable ).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with jest per se, but rather `fs.readFileSync` as some `fs` methods uses `process.cwd()` to compute pathing.

See [docs:](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths)
"The relative path to a filename can be used. Remember, however, that this path will be relative to process.cwd()."